# Tracking user progress on sharepoint through powerapps/ powerautomate

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

Short version: Is there a way to track the user ID and the title of the link a user clicks on microsoft sharepoint with powerautomate or powerapps?

Long version:I have a sharepoint which contains a tutorial. The tutorial consist of several web pages and each webpage contains a link "Next Topic". Whenever a user is clickling on the link, i would like to store the user id, webpage name and timestamp in an excel file in the sharepoint itself. I am currently looking for a powerautomate solution, however, i cannot find a way to trigger the flow when the user is clicking on the link and how to get the data for user ID and the webpage name.

Comment: I could be way off the track here but any reason why you wouldn't use something like Google Analytics?  It sounds like you need to embed it on your pages, not the approach of trying to capture the click.  In any case, PowerAutomate won't do that for you.  I guess you could in PowerApps but you'd need to surface the content in your own app with your own logic and just use SP as a storage platform.

Answer (score 1):

That's possible:

- Make your PowerAutomate flow with a trigger of receive http request.
- Your button on your website can make an http request, for example:

```
POST https://yourflow.com
HEADER Content-type: application/json
BODY {
    "webpage": "Page1", 
    "time": "UTCNow()", 
    "User": "UserNameFromOauthOrToken"
}
```

- Your power automate next step will be to create an item in your list with the values you passed from the request.

Comment: Hello @Iona Varga thank you for your quick reply. I have been trying to implement this however i keep failing since i am new to this. my sharepoint version is 16
Can you please provide a detailed explanation on how to proceed. Also i would like to know if JQuery must be implemented on the page to proceed with above usecase.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

This documentation explains in great detail every step you need to take to make requests :)